# adding correlation test results to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I'm trying to create a `ggplot` and add results of a correlation test I have done.
Something along the lines of:

```
p+annotate("text",x=12.5,y=15.25,label=c(cor.test$estimate,cor.test$p.value))
```

I keep getting error messages no matter what I try.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not a solution to your issue, but have you seen the packages corrplot/ggcorr

Comment: What are your errors exactly? If you show us some more code (example data and full plotting function), maybe someone finds a solution.

Comment: I have, though I already have a plot and just need to add annotations. Would like to link them to a corr test results directly

Comment: 'iriscor<-cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,color=Species))+
  labs(title="Sepal",y="Width",x=expression(paste(bold("Length"))),col="Species")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  annotate("text",x=12.5,y=15.25,label=c(iriscor$estimate,iriscor$p.value),parse=TRUE)
'

Comment: Related: [Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have actually managed to add stat details to the plot by using `stat_cor()` from the package `ggpubr`

```
library(ggpubr)
p+stat_cor(method="pearson")
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a package in development that can do this for you (`ggstatsplot` is on CRAN).

Here is an example of how to create correlation plot:

```
    ggstatsplot::ggscatterstats(data = iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
```

This will produce a plot that looks like the following (you can similarly get results from Spearman's rho (`type = 'spearman'`) or robust correlation test (`type = 'robust'`)):

[image]

Check out the documentation of the function for more.

Comment: @B.Shermeister Has this question been answered to your liking? If yes, please accept the answer (stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that this thread will be closed.

Comment: I am trying to create a `ggplot` that will show the result of a ttest (or corr test) on the plot. I am now using the line `annotate("text",x=1,y=10,label='atop(bold("P-value = 0.286"))',cex=7,parse=TRUE)`. The only problem is that I have to change the value manually each time. I would like to insert `ttest$p.value` instead of the number in the label

Comment: @B.Shermeister use ```label='atop(bold(paste("P-value = ", ttest$p.value))))```